# j_spring_security_check resulted in 401 (Android)

Tags: android, spring, authentication, spring-security, resttemplate

I am trying to login my API through spring security with rest template. I am able to login successfully in my web project but not with android app. I am trying to solve this issue for a long time but couldn't figure out.

Web code:

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

MultiValueMap<String, String> loginMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
loginMap.add("j_username", j_username);
loginMap.add("j_password", j_password);

HttpEntity<?> userEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(loginMap, new HttpHeaders());   

restTemplate.postForObject(PATH + "/j_spring_security_check", userEntity, String.class);
```

Android Code:

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

 MultiValueMap<String, String> loginMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
 loginMap.add("j_username", this.mEmail);
 loginMap.add("j_password", this.mPassword);

 HttpEntity<?> userEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(loginMap, new HttpHeaders());
 restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());

 restTemplate.postForObject(PATH + "/j_spring_security_check", userEntity, String.class);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem with adding two more converters.

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> loginMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    loginMap.add("j_username", this.mEmail);
    loginMap.add("j_password", this.mPassword);

    HttpEntity<?> userEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(loginMap, new HttpHeaders());

    restTemplate.postForObject(PATH + "/j_spring_security_check", userEntity, String.class);
```